# Is there a way that we can display seekbar above shaka control panel

Tags: javascript, shaka

I am new to Shakaplayer.Is there any way that we can display Shakaplayer range container above Shaka controls panel ? I want to display/position the seek bar above the control panel elements in shakaplayer.
Below image is my excepted behaviour which i am needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis i found the solution to display/position the seek bar above the control panel elements in shakaplayer

We can use the below css:

```
.shaka-bottom-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```